# SQL Server : Raiserror Trigger if new value is lower than or equals old value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I'm currently working on a trigger which should raise an error, if the new value is either lower than or equal to the old value.

This is my `number_table` which contains two columns:

```
Handle (int) | IK (numeric(18,0)
```

Now the IK content may change but should only change upwards, so I want to create the trigger to raise an error, if the new value is either equal or lower than the old value.

This is the trigger I got so far but it doesn't seem to work at all, as it does not raise an error:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_IK ON number_table
FOR UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM inserted i 
    JOIN deleted d ON i.Handle = d.Handle 
    WHERE i.IK < d.IK

    RAISERROR ('The new IK is either lower than or equals the old IK', 11, 1) with log
END
```

It should only raise an error if the new IK value is either lower than or equals the old IK value, does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to roll back if the new value is less than or equal old value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_IK ON number_table
FOR UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM inserted i join deleted d ON i.Handle = d.Handle 
        WHERE i.IK <= d.IK
        )
    RAISERROR ('The new IK is either lower than or equals the old IK', 11, 1) with log


END
```

Comment: Need to change the inequality check to <= per the requirements but still a +1 from me.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks. (I thought about it, but the original code has <).

Comment: The correct phrase  is "lower than" not "lower then"

Comment: @HLGEM I corrected my spelling...sorry English is not my mother tongue

Comment: @DVT Thank you, I'll try this out! Just another question, would you know, how I could get the values of i.IK and d.IK into the RAISERROR message as it would help me to identify the problem if I knew what the value was and to what it has been changed. Thanks in advance

Comment: What if you have more than 1 value that causes the error? Usually, the way I know to do it is first, capture the errors information (from the system), then add the error values (IK) to a variable table, commit/roll back the change, add the values from the variable table to an audit table, commit the change. Then throw the error using the information captured. See more information here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

Comment: I sorted the output myself now and used your trigger and it indeed worked perfectly fine! I found the error we had and could resolve it. Thanks again for your help